# Idiom for bad attached with good

Tags: idioms

I want to know an idiom for something like `if the thing is good it will have some negative also`. OR something like `with good comes bad`.

Let's say for a sentence "As they say ...................., nuclear energy has some negative aspects as well."

I know there are a few expressions like "curator's egg" and "double edged sword" but they don't fit in perfectly.

Comment: I don't think any such expression will fit well in a sentence about nuclear energy. "As they say, 'Every cloud has a silver lining', so nuclear energy has some negative aspects as well."  That nuclear energy would have negative aspects is pretty obvious. The question is does it have positive aspects.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I checked it just now and got more alternatives... :) Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common one is, ***[there's no rose without a thorn](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+no+rose+without+a+thorn)***:

> - Prov. to enjoy any beautiful or pleasant thing, you must endure something difficult or painful. *Mike: My bride is lovely and gracious, but I'm discovering that she has a terrible temper. Bill: There's no rose without a thorn.*

From: McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrases.

Answer (score 2):

Rosalind Fergusson, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs* (1983) lists a number of relevant sayings, in addition to the one that J O S H cites ("There's no rose without a thorn"):

> There are spots even in the sun.
>
> The best cloth may have a moth in it.
>
> No land without stones, or meat without bones.
>
> No silver without its dross.
>
> There is no pack of cards without a knave.
>
> Every light has its shadow.
>
> No summer, but has its winter.
>
> Wherever a man dwell, he shall be sure to have a thorn-bush near his door.
>
> No larder but has its mice.
>
> Every bean has its black.
>
> Every path has its puddle.

But my favorite from Fergusson's collection is this one:

> He who wants a mule without fault, must walk on foot.

Answer (score 0):

All that glitters is not gold.

This fits relatively well, "Barack Obama says nuclear energy may very well be able to facilitate immortality, but, unfortunately, all that glitters is not gold:

Ironically the very same (experimental) treatment is known to cause an ailment, for which the only cure is death, in any untreated individual who comes within 500 feet of a patient on the regimen."

Also, as a matter of personal principle i feel obligated to point out that the science suggests that of all energy sources, Nuclear seems to have the best ratio of energy output to safety (and practicality in terms of there being no shortage of nuclear fuel).

Less appropriate good bad idioms:

The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

What goes up must come down.